# how to encode char array with code page with c

Tags: c, windows, encoding, codepages, widechar

I have char array in C that I read from a binary file and I want to encode with spesific code page

For example I want to encode this char * with 1252 code page

```
char myArray[] = { 0xa0, 0x90, 0x91, 0x96, 0xb0 };
```

the result need to be `{ 0xa0, 0x90, 0x3F, 0x3F, 0xb0 }`

I know that `widechartomultibyte` can do that , but it need to get a wide char (like `00a0,0090,0091,0096,00b0` ) and I have only char * not wide char.

I can maybe convet c* to wide char with `MultiByteToWideChar` and then use `widechartomultibyte`  but when I do that it damages the encoding  and that looks strange to convert twice.

So how can I encoding char * with spesific code page in c with Windows ?

Comment: To transcode an encoded string we generally have to first decode to Unicode (UTF-16) via `MultiByteToWideChar`, for which we must know the source encoding. Otherwise, if we know the two encodings ahead of time, we can skip decoding to Unicode if we pre-compute a translation table. This is simple for translating between two single-byte codepages, but multi-byte codepages require a stateful conversion.

Comment: @eryksun I read this byte * from binary file so it don't have any encoding , I just want to encode it with code page like 1252 or 1250 and like that .    so I can't want use `MultiByteToWideChar` and then `widechartomultibyte` because when I use `MultiByteToWideChar` the buffer will be damage

Comment: If you don't know the encoding of the source data, how will you be able to re-encode it? "Hi, here's a book written in an unknown language. Translate it to French." How do you know that 0x91 0x96 map to 0x3f 0x3f?

Comment: @RaymondChen because I can encode byte with python `codecs.code_page_encode(1252, '\x91', 'replace')` and see that 0x91 and 0x96 map to 0x3F while I encoding with 1252 ,   So I need it with c , encode char * with spesific code page ,    the source file is binary file , like `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` and I want to encode the binary file with spesific code page

Comment: `'\x91'` is not a byte. It is a string. According to the documentation, when used in a string literal, the `\x` prefix "denote a Unicode character with the given value." Therefore, `\x91` is really U+0091. You can encode that character as a UTF-16LE code unit, and then pass that to WideCharToMultiByte.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ok, there is no faster way with c ?  maybe to read directly from binary file and encoding it to code page? or maybe encoding char * to code page without encoding it  first to  UTF-16LE ?  maybe the faster way will be to add 0x00 byte before each byte and then pass it to `WideCharToMultiByte`

Comment: @NoonkRiper, if you're in Python 3, then `'\x91'` is a Unicode string, and encoding U+0091 -> 0x3f has destroyed data. It won't roundtrip since it uses the default replacement byte `b"?"` (0x3f). The 'replace' handler uses `WideCharToMultiByte` with a best-fit mapping, which is only meant for an approximate display, e.g. "∞" (U+221E) maps to "8". On the other hand, the *byte* 0x91 decodes without loss to "‘" (U+2018). AFAIK, all of Microsoft's single-byte codepages roundtrip (i.e. `MultiByteToWideChar` -> `WideCharToMultiByte`) for all byte values, even if it's trivially 0x81 -> U+0081.

Comment: You can cast `char` to `wchar_t` as a quick decode to Latin-1. Codepage 1252 differs in that it maps characters to most of the C1 controls block, 0x80-0x9f.

Comment: "Storing only the bottom 8 bits of Unicode code points" is not an encoding I'm familiar with. it doesn't matter, because the WideCharToMultiByte and MultiByteToWideChar functions cannot convert directly between two 8-bit encodings. You have to go through UTF-16LE. So even if such a code page existed, you would still have to convert to UTF-16LE first. For this specific case, you might just want to use a 256-entry lookup table.

Comment: @eryksun  how can I quick cast char * to wchar_t* (that mean add 0x00 before each bytes) ?  and than I can pass it to `WideCharToMultiByte` with code page

Comment: If you have a `wchar_t` array named `wcArray` that's the same length as `myArray`, just loop over it and cast the values, e.g. `wcArray[i] = (wchar_t)myArray[i]`. You can encode it back to the original bytes using codepage 28591. Or simply cast the values back to `char`.

Comment: @eryksun I use this code `char myArray[] = { 0xa0, 0x90, 0x91, 0x96, 0xb0 };
    wchar_t wcArray[5];
    for (int i =0 ; i <5;i++)
    {
       
        wcArray[i] = (wchar_t)myArray[i];
    }
`     and I dont see that `wcArray` equal to `00a0, 0090, 0091, 0096, 00b0` so I can pass it to  `WideCharToMultiByte` and encode it with code page I want,  thank you about your help

Comment: "I don't see..." Tell us what you *do* see.